# Embedded Framework uploading Issue in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, frameworks, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a project with a third party framework, which is added under the "Embedded Binaries" tab in Project setting. When I'm trying to upload this project to iTunes Connect, I got the following errors.

The Xcode version is 7.3.1.

```
ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support."
ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support."

ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for ****.app/Frameworks/JSONModel.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64]'."
ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for ****.app/Frameworks/JSONModel.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64]'."

ERROR ITMS-90474: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown' in bundle 'com.***.****'."
ERROR ITMS-90474: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown' in bundle 'com.***.****'."

ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at ‘****.app/Frameworks/JSONModel.framework/JSONModel' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version."
ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at ‘****.app/Frameworks/JSONModel.framework/JSONModel' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version."

ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."
ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."

ERROR ITMS-90203: "Invalid architecture: Apps that include an app extension and framework must support arm64."
ERROR ITMS-90203: "Invalid architecture: Apps that include an app extension and framework must support arm64."

WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/****.app/Frameworks/JSONModel.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."
WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/****.app/Frameworks/JSONModel.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."
```

Answer (score 2):

The first error has to do with the Architecture you set in your project Build Settings. Check the screenshot below for such settings. Also if you Archive the app with a connected device that doesn't support 64bit, you can get that error. [image]

Comment: I can archive the app when I remove the embedded framework , and the settings which you mentioned is already set . I think the issue is with a binary with Embedded framework , please help me to resole this issue

Comment: Rijad, have you selected No for Build Active Architecture Only? Its seems to remove most of the error associated with building for 64bit.

Comment: Yes, archive with connected device was the problem for me.